# C# Post to browser fails, any ideas?

Tags: c#, browser, post

This is a quick and dirty app that only needs to work for a short period.  I'm not a developer so please don't hammer me.  The following code in asp works fine (secret info replaced with example.com and abc 123).

I know the below is very bad practice, but this is just for demonstration purpose:

```
<form method="post" action="https://example.com/asppage.aspx" id="frm_main">
<input type="hidden" name="STATE" id="STATE" value="ABC" />
<input type="hidden" name="VALIDATION" id="VALIDATION" value="123/>
<input type="submit" name="refresh_progress" value="Check Status" id="refresh_progress" /></form>
```

However, the same code in my c# post doesn't work:

```
string PostData = "STATE=ABC&amp;VALIDATION=123";
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://example.com/asppage.aspx", "_blank", Encoding.Default.GetBytes(PostData), "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n\r");
```

When the new browser window pops up, its the default asppage.aspx form with no data posted to it.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the example is missing some quote escapes (after value ABC and 123).. is that just in the post?

Comment: yes, just in this post, I corrected the typo.  The code does have the escapes correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're giving the webBrowser the html of the form, the POST data is a serialised format of the names and values of the form fields which is what you need to put in your Navigate method.

The postdata needs to be in the format:

`inputname1=value1&inputname2=value2&inputname3=value3`

You will also need to uri encode the string and include `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the fourth parameter in the method call.

Comment: Thanks for the direction, could you elaborate more please. I tried `string PostData="QUJD";` which is ABC encoded Base64.  Is that the correct "serialized" data?

Comment: I corrected the post format above per your suggestion, however, still no luck.  Looks like I'm getting closer, but just missing something small.

Comment: Change `STATE=ABC&amp;VALIDATION=123"` to `STATE=ABC&VALIDATION=123"`, the reason that `&amp;` exists is because the character has meaning in this situation of splitting up your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your POST format is completely wrong.

See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-data-set).

Comment: I corrected some typos, that link explains some post info, but I'm not a developer by trade, so it's a bit confusing.  Could you elaborate please.