# How to escape special Characters for post params in Navigate method

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, post

I've similar requirement as posted in this Question. [How to open IE with post info in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705201/how-to-open-ie-with-post-info-in-c)

I tried using answer provided by Andy S on the same questions. However, the issue I'm facing is I need to send 2 parameters (in my case **Request** and **Hash**) and I'm not sure how to achieve this using WebBrower's Navigate Method.

I've tried passing the Post Data by putting the String as 'Request=ABC&Hash=123" and the server didn't seem to recognize the parameters.

Below is the HTML which works

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Document Retrieval Service Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>    
<body onLoad="document.form1.submit();">
<form name="form1" method="post" action="http://abc.com/GetDoc/GetDoc.aspx">
    <!--Request: -->       
    <input name="Request" type="hidden" id="request" value="ABC">
<!--Hash:-->
   <input name="Hash" type="hidden" id="hash" value="123">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I'm able to make this work by passing additional arguments to Navigate method as per the answer provided in this question [C# Post to browser fails, any ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015000/c-sharp-post-to-browser-fails-any-ideas).

However, next issue now I'm facing is I've special character ampersand **&** in Request Parameter. I tried using `System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape` on the Request param, however, it still doesn't recognize the other parameter.

Edit2: I could make it working by using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode instead of using System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape

Thanks,
Prabhjot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it working by using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode instead of using System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape